# unable to display an image in php

Tags: php, header, content-type

In my project i am taking a json input of an image and converting it
 to png  like this..

```
$json = $_POST['output'];

$img = sigJsonToImage($json);//convert json to image

imagepng($img, 'signimage.png');//it saves the image correctly in local folder
```

But when i want to display it on the browser by the code

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($img);
```

It gaves error that image contains error and cannot be displayed .

please help me to figure out this problem thanks

Comment: What does the browser display if you comment the header: `//header('Content-Type: image/png');` ?

Comment: perhaps the eerror lies within the "sigJsonToImage" function - post that function too?

Comment: it shows an encryped string like �PNG  IHDR�7�7���IDATx��yp���n���Vkɒ,����QhI�di\�-�Cf�N���I���L��3�$3��H�&-a�N�!@'�IL'

Comment: there's nothing **encrypted** there.

Comment: @TamilSelvan Out of curiosity, did you reject my suggested edit or was it not visible ?

Comment: @spenibus I didn't reject your suggested edit

Answer (score 2):

> It gaves error that image contains error and cannot be displayed .

You must be outputing more than you think.

- Check PHP files for spaces/new lines before `<?php` tags and if you use `?>` tags, check them too (or drop `?>` completely).
- You may want to add `exit();` just after `imagepng($img);` but if you "pollute" data earlier, it won't help.
- I'd **download** this image (i.e. `wget http://localhost/script.php` and peek using binary editor to ensure what I (most likely) have before png signature:

[image]